# Thread initialization with templates and variadic templates

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates

I need to init `std::thread` with templates.

```
class Loader
{
    template <class T, class ...TArgs>
    static void work(T t, TArgs ...args)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
    template <class T, class ...TArgs>
    static void Load(T t, TArgs ...args)
    {

        thread thr = thread(Loader::work,t,args...);
        thr.join()
    }
}
```

I tied that on my custom classes initialization and its worked, but i dont know what should i do with threads.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify types used in a template:

```
thread thr = thread(Loader::work<T, TArgs...>,t,args...);
```